# Relation between row space and column space resp. null space and left null space over general rings

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a ring and $M\in\text{Mat}(R,m\times n)$ a matrix for $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. What results are known about the relation between column space (cs, image) and row space (rs), resp. null space (ker, kernel or right kernel) and left null space (lker, left kernel)?

When $R=k$ is a field, there are many early results from standard linear algebra, e.g.
$$\dim \text{cs} + \dim \text{ker} = n$$
$$\dim \text{rs} + \dim \text{lker} = m$$
$$\dim \text{cs} = \text{rk}_{\text{col}} = \text{rk} = \text{rk}_{\text{row}} = \dim \text{rs}$$
etc. From this one deduces that rs and cs are (non-canonically) isomorphic and in case of $m=n$ the same holds for the two kernels. one can also involve transposition in these results.

I have done some toy examples over $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

A. $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}$, then $\text{ker}=\langle\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\rangle\simeq\langle\begin{pmatrix}1& 1\end{pmatrix}\rangle=\text{lker}$ are rank-1 free modules. Similarly for the generated spaces $\text{cs}=\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 3\end{pmatrix}\rangle\simeq\langle\begin{pmatrix}1& 2\end{pmatrix}\rangle=\text{rs}$.

B. $M=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1\\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$, then $\text{ker}=\langle\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\rangle\simeq\langle\begin{pmatrix}0& 2\end{pmatrix}\rangle=\text{lker}$ are rank-1 modules isomorphic to the unique proper ideal in $R$, while $\text{cs}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}:x\in R,y\in\langle 2\rangle\right\}\simeq\left\{\begin{pmatrix}y& x\end{pmatrix}:x\in R,y\in\langle 2\rangle\right\}=\text{rs}$.

To me it seems that there should be a well established theory for this, or at least references for well known counterexamples. But the sources I consulted, [McDonald (Linear Algebra over Commutative Rings )](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781003065197/linear-algebra-commutative-rings-bernard-mcdonald), [Brown (Matrices over commutative rings)](https://www.worldcat.org/title/matrices-over-commutative-rings/oclc/26398890), [Roman (Advanced Linear Algebra)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-72831-5), do not dwell on that - unless I overlooked something. Even Bourbaki in Algèbre Ch. 2.12 seems to define rank only in the context of fields.

**Update.** However, Bourbaki in Algèbre Ch. 2.2 §5 deals in some form with such questions. He works with dual modules and in the context of potentially non-commutative rings. Using identifications of free modules with their duals, resp. of left and right modules over commutative rings, this should give some results in the direction indicated above. A more fitting reference is still welcome.

Any references to textbooks and results in that direction are appreciated.

Comment: I can recommend to first formulate these questions in terms of linear maps between two free modules F and G of rank n and m. The modules you are asking for have natural representations in this setting. Also involving the adjoint linear map (transpose, to switch between left and right notions).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thank you for your advice. Do you know results in that context? Are the image of a morphism of free modules and the image of its adjoint isomorphic? Are there counterexamples? What about kernels? Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 4):

$\def\Hom{\text{Hom}}\def\Ext{\text{Ext}}\def\Im{\text{Im}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$
I think that the right question is whether or not $\Im(f^{\ast}) \cong \Im(f)^{\ast}$, not whether or not $\Im(f^{\ast}) \cong \Im(f)$. (Notation explained below.) Specifically, I'll show:

(1) There is always a natural injection $\Im(f^{\ast}) \hookrightarrow \Im(f)^{\ast}$.

(2) This injection is an isomorphism if $R$ is self-injective, which is the case for $\mathbb{Z}/D \mathbb{Z}$, and more generally, for any $0$-dimensional Gorenstein ring.

(3) In the very particular case of $\mathbb{Z}/D \mathbb{Z}$, every finitely generated module is isomorphic to its dual, so we have $\Im(f^{\ast}) \cong \Im(f)^{\ast} \cong \Im(f)$ in that case. I know of very few rings for which every finitely generated module is isomorphic to its dual, though, so I think this will be rare.

**Notation:** I'll work with commutative rings throughout, but I think that non-commutativity is just a matter of being careful about lefts and rights.
For an $R$-module $M$, the dual $R$-module $M^{\ast}$ is $\Hom_R(M,R)$. I'll write $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ for the pairing $M^{\ast} \times M \to R$. Given $f : M \to N$, the adjoint map $f^{\ast} : N^{\ast} \to M^{\ast}$ is defined by
$$\langle f^{\ast}(n^{\ast}), m \rangle = \langle n^{\ast}, f(m) \rangle. \qquad (\clubsuit)$$

Throughout, let $M$ and $N$ be free $R$-modules and $M \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} N$ an $R$-linear map.

**The map $\Im(f^{\ast}) \to \Im(f)^{\ast}$** We need to construct an $R$-bilinear pairing $\Im(f^{\ast}) \times \Im(f) \to R$.
Given $m^{\ast} \in \Im(f^{\ast})$ and $n \in \Im(f)$, choose preimages $n^{\ast} \in N^{\ast}$ and $m \in M$. Then
$$\langle m^{\ast}, m \rangle = \langle f^{\ast}(n^{\ast}), m \rangle = \langle n^{\ast}, f(m) \rangle = \langle n^{\ast}, n \rangle. \qquad (\diamondsuit)$$
where the middle equality is $(\clubsuit)$. We will define our pairing $\Im(f^{\ast}) \times \Im(f) \to R$ by $(m^{\ast}, n) := \langle m^{\ast}, m \rangle = \langle n^{\ast}, n \rangle$.

**Well-definedness** Using the left hand side of $(\diamondsuit)$, we see that $(m^{\ast}, n)$ is independent of the choice of $n^{\ast}$; using the right hand side of $(\diamondsuit)$, we see that $(m^{\ast}, n)$ is independent of the choice of $m$. So $(\ , \ )$ is well-defined. It is easy to check bilinearity. So we get a map $\Im(f^{\ast}) \to \Im(f)^{\ast}$.

**Injectivity** Suppose that $m^{\ast} \in \Im(f^{\ast})$ maps to the $0$ map in $\Im(f)^{\ast}$. In other words, suppose that, for all $m \in M$, we have $(m^{\ast}, f(m))=0$. But $(m^{\ast}, f(m)) = \langle m^{\ast}, m \rangle$, so this says that $m^{\ast}(m)=0$ for all $m \in M$, which means that $m^{\ast}$ is the $0$ element of $M^{\ast}$. This checks injectivity. We have now checked all of claim (1).

**Surjectivity, if $R$ is self-injective** Recall that an $R$-module $I$ is called [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module) if, for any $R$-modules $A \subseteq B$, and any homomorphism $A \to I$, the homomorphism can be extended to a homomorphism $B \to I$.

Suppose now that $R$ is an injective $R$-module, and consider $\Im(f) \subseteq N$. For any homomorphism $\phi : \Im(f) \to R$, there is an element $n^{\ast} : N \to R$ extending $\phi$. In other words, $n^{\ast}$ is an element of $N^{\ast}$ which maps to $\phi$ under the composite $N^{\ast} \to \Im(f^{\ast}) \to \Im(f)^{\ast}$. We have shown that every $\phi \in \Im(f)^{\ast}$ is in the image of $\Im(f^{\ast})$, proving $(2)$.

Finally, $(3)$ is easy to verify. Every $\ZZ/D \ZZ$ module is, in particular, a $\ZZ$-module, so it is a direct sum of modules of the form $\ZZ/k \ZZ$ and $\ZZ$. But such modules are $\ZZ/D \ZZ$ modules only if $k$ divides $D$ (and $\ZZ$ is not a $\ZZ/D \ZZ$ module). We have $(\ZZ/k \ZZ)^{\ast} \cong \ZZ/k \ZZ$, and dual distributes over finite direct sums, so every $\ZZ/D \ZZ$-module is self dual.

Comment: "I know of very few rings for which every finitely generated module is isomorphic to its dual, though, so I think this will be rare." Isn't this true for any $R/a$ where $R$ is a PID and $a \in R$ is nonzero? Your argument seems to prove this just as well.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, that's right. And you can replace "PID" by "Dedekind Domain", since we can always localize near $a$ before quotienting, and Dedekind Domains are locally PID's. That is the full list of rings that I know with this property.